# Solving ODE using SymPy with differential boundary conditions

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations, boundary

I want to solve the following ODE after u(x):

eqdiff = sp.Eq(q + EA * d2u,0)

where:

x,EA,l,q0 = sp.symbols('x EA l q0')

q = q0

u = sp.Function('u')

du = sp.Derivative(u(x), x)

d2u = sp.Derivative(u(x), x, 2)

I tried

sp.dsolve(eqdiff, u(x), ics = {u(l): 0, du.subs(x,0)-100000*u(0):0}) ,

but this did not work.
The error message is: ValueError: Enter boundary conditions of the form ics={f(point): value, f(x).diff(x, order).subs(x, point): value}
So apparently, for the boundary conditions, one can only set u(x) OR a derivative of it and not set the function in relation with its derivative.

My question is: How can I implement the second boundary condition du.subs(x,0)-100000*u(0):0 such that the code works?